# Scala dataframe calling function inside withColumn?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is what I am trying to do, I have two tables that have exactly the same column names.

Table look somewhat like this:

```
-----------
A  B  C  D 
-----------
1  2  3  4
5  6  3  4
7  8  3  4
```

The logic of the problem I need to have is, compare A B C D columns in Table1 with Table2. If A,B match each other, return a new column with value 0, else return 0. If C from table A is 3, return 0, else return 1. Only one value should be returned for each row, priority: C>D>A=B.

I joined two tables(dataFrames), result in a combinedDf. This is how I join them: `Table1.join(Table2,table1($"A")=table2($"A"))`

So here is what I did:

```
def func(A:mutable.WrappedArray[String],B:mutable.WrappedArray[String],C:String,D:String) = 
{if(C=="3") "0";
 else if(D=="4")"1";
 else if ((0 to A.length-1).exists(i => A(i) == B(i)))"0" else "1"}
```

For this function I want to put A,B columns from Table1 in to one array and A,B column from Table2 into another array and running a for loop to check the equality. (I need the array because for real case, I have a random number of columns I need to compare).

And here is how I call the function.

```
combinedDf.withColumn("returnVal",func(array(col("table1.A"),col("table1.B")),
array(col("table2.A"),col("table2.B")),col("table1.C"),col("table1.D")))
```

But it's just doesn't work, even though I put the columns inside array using the array function its' still telling me type mismatch.

Error Message: `<console:67>: error: type mismatch; found:org.apache.spark.Column required: String`
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please send first part of the error message?

Comment: how are you joining the two dataframes? please update that part too.

Comment: @Ramesh Maharjan updated

Comment: is the join working?  I guess its not because your join statement is totally wrong.

Comment: according to the join it seems that column A of both dataframes matches for join purpose. Is that true?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yes, A is the key column, tho in my real case, there are two key columns

Comment: @Anna you didn't answer my previous question about join. And what do you mean by there are two key columns?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I have two dataframe, exactly same column names, two the columns are considered "key columns" use for the join conditions. join on A=B, C=D etc

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, however help me understand one thing why do you need to combine the dataframes, and what you mean by if A and B matches(my assumption is per row, am i right?), If your A,B,C,D columns are string then change integer to String.

```
def func(A:Integer,B:Integer,C:Integer,D:Integer) = 
    {
     if(C == 3) "0"
     else if(D == 4) "1"
     else if (A == B) "0"
     else "1"
    }
    val udfFunc = udf(func _)

    combinedDf.withColumn("returnVal",
      udfFunc(col("table1.A"), col("table1.B"), 
              col("table1.C"),col("table1.D")
             )
      )
```

Comment: like I said I need the array type because in real case I would have random number of columns, so I can't just define like 50 parameters in my udf. Join is because udf doesn't work with two dataframes, whatever data I give the udf must come from the same dataframe

Comment: Then you can use concat_ws(",",Seq(col("table1.A", col("table1.B")) as first argument and similarly second argument. and in the UDF first two argument would be String and  in 3rd else if of your func first split the columns by comma (,) to get the array then your code should work fine. This way you can combine dynamic no of column values and pass as one string and then in your udf you can parse it get the array and perform the logic. Hope that helps.

Comment: still type error, it said found: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column